# Extracting a specific Data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, field

I have a mongodb which I want to extract some specific data. There multi level of array in the data. 
However I want to extract a specific data based on a parameter. But I am receiving all the data in the document.
This is my query.

```
model.find({
    'level1.level_name': level,
    'level1.step.field_name': subject,
    'level1.step.sub_step.field_name1':'data1',
    'level1.step.sub_step.field_name2':'data2'
})
.select(['level1.step.sub_step.field_name3']);
```

Instead of mongodb producing data based on the query above it produces all the field_name3 inside of the document.

How can I get only the specific data I want based on the query/criteria I have given above

This is a sample of what was produced. The actual result is way longer than these

```
[{"_id":"7a45339dab9e1d07946132ac","level1":[{},{},{},{},{"step":[
    {"sub_step":[{"field_name3":20},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70},{"field_name3":10},**{"field_name3":70}**]},
    {"sub_step":[]},
    {"sub_step":[{"field_name3":20},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70}]},
    {"sub_step":[{"field_name3":20},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70}]},
    {"sub_step":[{"field_name3":20},{"field_name3":10},{"field_name3":70},{"field_name3":10},**{"field_name3":70}**]}
]},{},{}]}]
```

What I actually was expecting was the last field_name3 in the first row only. I do not have a foreknowledge of what is in that field

I only have the query, also as it can be seen many of the field have similar data. Some of the remaining parts are not similar like as
it is shown above

Comment: can you provide sample of documents, and what you expect as result

Comment: This is the sample document as stated above. The full result would be too long for the page and the wysiwyg is complaining  that there was too much code in comparison to the comment. So I had to just put up the sample. It is basically a proper sample/representative of the program

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MongoDB driver, you should use a projection.

```
model.find({
    'level1.level_name': level,
    'level1.step.field_name': subject,
    'level1.step.sub_step.field_name1':'data1',
    'level1.step.sub_step.field_name2':'data2'
}).project({'level1.step.sub_step.field_name3': true, _id: false})
```

See: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#project

Comment: It did not work I did not notice your comment on MongoDB driver. I am using mongoose. Thanks very much for the help